# Git deletes files in working directory after switching branch

Tags: git

I have a problem with 1 file in a git repository.
The file exists in [develop] and also in [feature/x]

After I switch from [develop] to [feature/x] the file is deleted from the working folder and when I do a git status it is marked for delete.

When I do git reset --hard the file is back.

The problem only occurs with a specific file and I can't figure out what the cause is.

Comment: Is the file part of .gitignore (in one of the branches)?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that in feature/x the file is all lower case and in develop it is in camel case. Git is configured with ignorecase is true. The file is not in any .gitignore file